# Fetch csv using Python mysql connector

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am trying to fetch a .csv file stored in a Mysql database as a BLOB.

I first tried with a .txt file and everything works perfectly, but I now have issue when it comes to a csv file : though the SELECT query works on Mysql, it doesn't seem to be the case on python. This error keeps appearing :

```
SystemError: <built-in method fetch_row of _mysql_connector.MySQL object at 0x00000172B02080B0> returned a result with an error set
```

Here is my code :

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='password', database='test')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

query = ("SELECT * FROM blob_test where id=1")
cursor.execute(query)

test_file = cursor.fetchone()
```

FYI, I am just testing with a simple table with 3 columns : (id SMALLINT, name VARCHAR, file BLOB)

Comment: You can check your database connection by trying to execute a query without any database specific things like: `cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")`.

Comment: I don't think it is a connection problem. The query does correctlyreturn my current mysql version `('5.7.23-log',)`. I also tried to fetch a txt file of my db, and it worked properly.

Comment: Interesting. Try a different API like `pymysql`. Also your error message seems cut off.

Comment: May be there is a problem with reading (large files) from the BLOB field. Have you tried ``query = ("SELECT `id`, `name` FROM blob_test where id=1")``

Comment: @Parfait I just checked and except from the traceback, the error message is complete. Also, I would like to try fix the problem before changing API.

Comment: @Henrik No I didn't. But this new query gives me the proper result ! Maybe there is a size issue, though I only used a 2ko csv file. Any ideas to overcome this issue ?

Comment: @Nherv I also think this can be an issue of the used database connector as Parfait already commented. I would try with a different connector (maybe another version already works).

Comment: @Nherv ... reason I mention using a different API is to see if this is a bug in `mysql.connector` or your database. Possibly the CSV was not properly stored as blob. Please show how you uploaded the content and even the TXT version.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your point. I'll try with a new connector then. I uploaded both of my files using the standard mysql query : `INSERT INTO blob_test (id, name, file) VALUES (NULL, 'file_name', LOAD_FILE('file_path'));`. When doing a SELECT query on my windows command prompt, the content seems fine.

Comment: I changed my API to pymsql and eveything worked properly ! Thanks guys for your help. Another question : I am now trying to fetch an image (PNG file). The query give me a byte result. Is it possible in Python to display or save this image ?

Comment: I actually found a solution to my issue. Thank guys